# How to group list<T> into List<List<T>> based on some criteria in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of arrays like this:

```
List<string[]> definitions

  MATERIAL  "STEEL"    TYPE "Steel"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 7833.414
  MATERIAL  "STEEL"    SYMTYPE "Isotropic"  E 2.038902E+10  
  MATERIAL  "STEEL"  FY 3.515348E+07  FU 4.569952E+07 
  MATERIAL  "STEEL"  HYSTYPE "Kinematic"  SSTYPE "Simple"   
  MATERIAL  "CONC"    TYPE "Concrete"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 2402.616
  MATERIAL  "CONC"    SYMTYPE "Isotropic"  E 2.531051E+09  U 0.2
  MATERIAL  "CONC"    FC 2812279
  MATERIAL  "CONC"  HYSTYPE "Concrete"  ENERGYDEGFACT 0
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"    TYPE "Other"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 7833.414
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"    SYMTYPE "Isotropic"  E 2.038902E+10
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  DESIGNTYPE "OTHER"  
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  HYSTYPE "Elastic"  IOTENSION 0.01
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  STRAIN -1 STRESS -1 
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  STRAIN 0 STRESS 0 POINTID "A"  
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  STRAIN 1 STRESS 1
```

I want to be able create a list like this out of the `definitions` list:

```
List<List<string[]>> objects
```

and separate the lists based on the second element in each array:

```
  MATERIAL  "STEEL"    TYPE "Steel"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 7833.414
  MATERIAL  "STEEL"    SYMTYPE "Isotropic"  E 2.038902E+10  
  MATERIAL  "STEEL"  FY 3.515348E+07  FU 4.569952E+07 
  MATERIAL  "STEEL"  HYSTYPE "Kinematic"  SSTYPE "Simple"  


  MATERIAL  "CONC"    TYPE "Concrete"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 2402.616
  MATERIAL  "CONC"    SYMTYPE "Isotropic"  E 2.531051E+09  U 0.2
  MATERIAL  "CONC"    FC 2812279
  MATERIAL  "CONC"  HYSTYPE "Concrete"  ENERGYDEGFACT 0


  MATERIAL  "OTHER"    TYPE "Other"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 7833.414
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"    SYMTYPE "Isotropic"  E 2.038902E+10
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  DESIGNTYPE "OTHER"  
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  HYSTYPE "Elastic"  IOTENSION 0.01
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  STRAIN -1 STRESS -1 
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  STRAIN 0 STRESS 0 POINTID "A"  
  MATERIAL  "OTHER"  STRAIN 1 STRESS 1
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried thus far?

Comment: Sounds good.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ Amy I'm still trying!

Comment: The data in your question is very difficult to parse so I've no idea what you're actually asking here.

Comment: @DavidG I do not want to parse it actually right now. Just create a List of Lists containing string arrays.

Comment: By parse I mean "I don't understand how the data you have posted fits into the data structure you say you have"

Comment: I have split each line you see here in a single array of strings. For example: MATERIAL  "STEEL"    TYPE "Steel"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 7833.414 is array1 and so on. all of these arrays are in a list. Now what I want is to create another list that contains lists of arrays. And these inner lists contain these string arrays. The criteria for this separation is second element in each array!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `GroupBy`?

```
var listOfGroups = definitions.GroupBy(x => x.Material);
```

You will get a list of elements, which has a `Key` and a list of the grouped objects.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I have arrays here in my list. And I want to be able to separate them based on the second element. STEEL or CONC for example-

Comment: If you paste some code that actually initialises the lists (arrays) and shows the structure of them, it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Than just GroupBy second elemtn in array:

```
var groups = definitions.GroupBy(x => x[1]);
```

It's not a List what you get, it's `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string[]>>`  But i think it's exact what you are looking for.

Comment: I have done this so far. It does not give me the structure I want.

Comment: var objects= definitions
                .GroupBy(b => b[1])
                .Select(o => o.ToList())
                .ToList();

Comment: I think I found it.

Answer (score -2):

Try using DataTable and using LINQ you can filter it

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
//Add the data in it
dt.Where() or dt.Select();
```

Comment: Why are you making List<List<string[]>> complex collection make it simple @Vahid